# When the New Testament calls the church “the temple"

Tags: temple, local-church

When the New Testament calls the church “the temple,” it doesn’t mean the buildings in which we gather. It means the people. Why is that?

> 1 Cor 3:16, 17 - Do you not know that you yourselves are God’s temple,
> and that God’s Spirit dwells in you? 17If anyone destroys God’s
> temple, God will destroy him; for God’s temple is holy, and you are
> that temple.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take to tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mutepa. Just to add, by the way, that a few years after Paul wrote that, Herod's Temple in Jerusalem was utterly destroyed by the Romans (in A.D.70). Since then, no Jewish temple has been built, no sacrifices offered, and so the Christians would grasp very powerfully what he meant, Jesus having foretold the ruin of the Jerusalem temple about 30 years before it happened. In Hermeneutics, the more relevant details you can add helps bolster the case for asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "temple" never refers to the physical building where Christians meet simply because, such did not exist for nearly 300 years after Jesus.

However, the New Testament makes much use of Sanctuary imagery in at least five different ways:

1. As a teaching device of Jesus and the plan of salvation (as in the Old Testament).  Specifically, many of the elements of the sanctuary are explained.

- The sacrificial lamb represented Jesus (John 1:29, Rom 8:3, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19, Heb 9:12)
- Jesus’ teaching is closely associated with water (in the laver), John 4:13, 14.
- Jesus was the bread of life as symbolized by the shew bread (John 6:35-51)
- The light of the Menorah represented Jesus (John 8:12, 9:5)
- Jesus was the door (John 10:7-9)
- Jesus opened the curtain to the Most Holy Place (2 Cor 3:13-16, Heb 6:19, 9:3, 10:20)
- The smoke from the altar of incense represents the prayers of the saints (Rev 5:8, 8:3, 4)
- The Ark of the covenant, especially the “mercy seat” represented the throne of God and its implied mercy (Ex 25:17-22, Heb 9:5, 4:16, Rom 3:23-25)
- Jesus is represented as our great High Priest and intercessor in heaven (Heb 4:16, 7:25, 10:22, Rom 8:26, 34, 1 John 2:1, 2, 1 Tim 2:5, John 14:6)

2. The Temple represented Jesus’ own (physical) body (John 2:19-21)
3. The Temple represented a Christian’s body (1 Cor 6:19, 20).
4. The Temple represented the community of believers (or church) (1 Cor 3:16, 17, 2 Cor 6:16, Eph 2:19-22)
5. The earthly temple represented the heavenly temple (Heb 8:2, 9:11).  This is not to suggest that the heavenly temple is anything physically like the earthly one – far from it (the heavenly temple does not have an altar of burnt offering, nor does it have embroidered angels on the curtains, it is inconceivable that it is constructed of dyed rams' skin and beavers' hides, etc).  The Heavenly temple is nowhere described and is vastly grander and beyond description.  However, the earthly temple/tabernacle represented the work of Jesus and His mediatorial work of intercession as our Great High priest in Heaven (Heb 4:16, 7:25, 10:22, Rom 8:26, 34, 1 John 2:1, 2, 1 Tim 2:5, John 14:6) as shown above.

Thus, the metaphor of the temple representing the Christian community is just one of several ways the temple was used metaphorically.

Answer (score 0):

At that time Christian churches, that is to say, congregations, did not have separate buildings for worship, but they still hoped to win Jews to the right cause of coming to belief in Christ as the true Messiah and Savior, so they not only gathered separately (cd. 1 Cor. 11:21), but were also going for prayers and theological debates to the buildings of synagogues and the Temple of Solomon (cf. Acts 3:1-12).

However, presenting a believer as a “temple” is a Pauline metaphor for showing a new intimacy of Christians with God, for as Solomon’s Temple is the place where true God resides, and as pagan temples are places where their gods reside, so are Christians living temples in whom God resides.

As Paul says, “not I am any longer alive, but Christ lives in me” (Galatians 2:20). Elsewhere, in 1 Corinthians 3:13 he speaks about Christians building the metaphoric houses of their salvation on the Rock who is Christ.

So, as the new and unprecedented intimacy with God came to humanity through Christ, then it is meet and proper to use a metaphor of a temple with reference to believers in whom God dwells and powerfully works (Colossians 1:29).

Answer (score 0):

**Excellent Question** This question brings up a very important aspect of the Christian religion! It presents a reality in essence that the Old Testament presented symbolically: the manifest Presence of God on earth!

While the Israelites traveled from Egypt to the Promised Land, they occasionally set up a Tabernacle. This Tabernacle was divided into three sections, one of which was the Holy of Holies, an inner sanctum. Here, was placed an Ark (gold-plated chest), over which the Presence of God hovered in amazing glory and holy splendor.

When the Temple was built later in Solomon's time, the Presence of God also entered into the inner sanctum with great glory.

**New Testament** However, in the New Testament, the Presence of God no longer dwelt in the Temple because of the wickedness of the people. The curtain separating the Holy of Holies was ripped apart showing the absence of God's Presence.  Eventually the physical Temple itself was destroyed by the Roman conquerors (70A.D.).

But according to the Book of Hebrews (q.v.) all that was symbolic, any way. It pictured a new reality:  the Presence of God in the heart (inner sanctum) of the Believer!!! God's Presence was to indwell men and women via the **Holy Spirit**, which Jesus said *the Father would give to the Church.* (See John 15-17)

Hence the Believer is the "Temple of the Holy Spirit" (God). (1 Corinthians 3:16) And so, the Believers in congregate (the Church) are the Temple of God, too. And the amazing thing is that God manifests His Holy Spirit Presence there by the use of **Charismatic Gifts.**: Prophecies, healings, exorcisms, edifications, revelations, etc. (1 Corinthians 12-14) All to the glory and praise of God Almighty!